# Is wiring a 240 volt heater from a sub panel different from wiring it to the main panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, heater, subpanel

Since the neutral and ground are isolated in a sub panel, is wiring a 240 volt heater from a sub panel different from wiring it to the main panel?

Answer (score 3):

No, as long as you land the ground wire on the ground bus of course -- but that's a caveat when wiring *anything* to a subpanel.  (I'd run it using /3 NM so that there's a neutral run to the heater in case it's needed for outlets on a baseboard setup or something like that...and in that case, you also have to remember to land the neutral wire on the neutral bus, but again, that's just like any other circuit.)

The hots hook up just like any other 220V circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as well:
240V doesn't rely on the neutral anyway. Although some loads require running 2 hots and a neutral, it isn't there to get 240. Like the last answer said though, it's all wired the exact same way.

Isolation of the neutral and ground is just to prevent any power from running the ground line back to the main.